# Filtering out the product on the page being shown in a carousel of all of the products

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react, and I am working on a product where I want to have a carousel of all of the products on an individual product's page with the exception of the product that is being shown. Currently, I am able to display the carousel on the page with all of the products, but I am having difficultly figuring out how to filter out the product that is being displayed. Since the products are filtered by a slug and a category, I have all of construction of the carousel and the data associated with it on the my CarouselForProduct.js. I think I would need a filter to do this, so I was thinking it would be something like `{products.filter((x) => x.Id.includes(Id !== product_id)).map((product) => (...))}`, but this doesn't seem to work. I would really appreciate any or guidance on how to do this. Thank you!

CarouselForProductPage.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Product from '../components/Product';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';
import CarouselProducts, {CarouselItem} from '../components/CarouselProducts';
import ProductForCarousel from '../components/ProductForCarousel';


 export default function CarouselForProductPage() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
    const { loading, error, products } = productList;
    useEffect(() =>{
        dispatch(listProducts({}));
    }, [dispatch]);

    

    
  return (
       
      <div> 
        <CarouselProducts>
        {products.map((product) => (
                    <ProductForCarousel product={product}></ProductForCarousel>
            ))}
        </CarouselProducts>
      </div>
    
  );
}
```

ProductScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { createReview, detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import { PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/productConstants';
import '../components/Accordion.css'
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { FiPlus, FiMinus } from 'react-icons/fi';
import {FaStar} from 'react-icons/fa';
import Progress_bar from '../components/Progress_bar';
import StarRating from '../components/StarRating';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';
import CarouselProducts, {CarouselItem} from '../components/CarouselProducts';
import ProductForCarousel from '../components/ProductForCarousel';
import CarouselForProductPage from '../components/CarouselForProductPage';


export default function ProductScreen(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productId = props.match.params.id;

  
    const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
    const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
    const {products } = productList;
    const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
    const { userInfo } = userSignin;


const product_id = {productId}

  
    return (
      <div className="row top">

        <CarouselForProductPage>

        </CarouselForProductPage>
      
    </div>

      );
      
}
```

ProductsForCarousel.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Rating from './Rating';

export default function ProductForCarousel(props) {
  const { product } = props;
  
  

  
    return ( 
      <div key={product._id} className="card_product_carousel">
        <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
          <img className="small" src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
        </Link>
        <div className="card-body">
        <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
          <h2><div className="product_carousel_name">{product.name}</div></h2>
        </Link>
        <Rating
          rating={product.rating}
          numReviews={product.numReviews}
        ></Rating>
        <div className="card_price">${product.price}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: _something like `{products.filter((x) => x.Id.includes(Id !== product_id))`_ <-- Please try `{products.filter((x) => x.Id !== product_id)`

Comment: @jsN00b Hi, so I added that to my CarouselForProductPage.js: ```<CarouselProducts> {products.map((product) => ( <ProductForCarousel product= {products.filter((x) => x.Id !== product_id)}></ProductForCarousel>
 ))} </CarouselProducts> ``` and imported product_id from my ProductScreen.js to CarouselForProductPage.js, but now, I am not getting any of the images/data for the products in the carousel.

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that. Would you please add the data of `products` as well as the value in `product_id`? I'm interested in checking the elements of the `products` array and specfically looking at the `id` prop of each element.

Comment: Hi, I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're asking for, but I added my ProductsFor Carousel.js document, which shows all of the parts of the data that should be coming through. The actual data for each product is stored within my mongodb database. One of the ids is : 624bc1a50f91078261ab650d.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info (although that isn't quite what I had in mind). Appreciate it. I observe this: `product._id`. So, I want to try something like this: `{products.filter((x) => x._id !== product_id)`. Instead of `x.Id`, it is `x._id`. If that doesn't work, then please also try: `x["_id"]`.